# Liquibase dbms mssql precondition does not work on Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, liquibase

I am trying to see why did this change set get applied in an Oracle DB when the precondition clearly states mssql

It is a simple change set. Update the Column CategoryType to AppServiceUser of UserTable where it is ''
and in roll back put it back to ''
So it failed in Rollback as the rollback SQL should not work in Oracle. That's how i came to know that it ran in Oracle.

```
<changeSet id="ChangeSet-1" author="Coder" failOnError="false">
        <preConditions
                onFailMessage="Failed Failed"
                onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <dbms type="mssql"/>
            <ext:columnIsNotNullable tableName="UserTable" columnName="CategoryType"/>
            <sqlCheck expectedResult="1">SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE CategoryType = '') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END</sqlCheck>
        </preConditions>
        <comment> Insert 'AppServiceUser' default value to UserTable.CategoryType</comment>
        <sql>UPDATE UserTable SET CategoryType = 'AppServiceUser' WHERE CategoryType = ''</sql>
        <rollback>
            <sql>UPDATE UserTable SET CategoryType = ''</sql>
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
```

My question is

1- why didn't the precondition dbms=mssql work when this change set was ran against Oracle and

2- what is the difference between putting this in the precondition and putting it in the change set directly.
like

```
<changeSet id="ChangeSet-1" author="Coder" failOnError="false" dbms="mssql">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing it seems that when you add it as an attribute to the change set itself,

```
<changeSet id="ChangeSet-1" author="Coder" failOnError="false" dbms="mssql">
```

it is altogether skipped and is not listed in the databasechangelog.

If it is added as a precondition then ( in our case as above) it executed but in EXECTYPE it put MARK_RAN instead of executed, hence the roll back was ran in our case in Oracle and failed. (MARK_RAN could have been due to any of the reasons in preconditions though)

I think the rollback should have a dbms attribute as sometimes a roll back is done differently for similar SQLs.